# Is it bad practice to repurpose asyncValidate for integrating a Promise-returning validation library?

Tags: validation, redux-form

My understanding is that `asyncValidate()` is provided to support the "Is this username taken?" and similar use cases where server-side logic is required to run in order to validate one or more fields before the actual form submission.

I've been looking at integrating the Joi-inspired Yup library (https://github.com/jquense/yup) as detailed in this blog post:
http://www.davidboyne.co.uk/2016/04/29/redux-form-validation-with-yup.html

I like yup's declarative paradigm, but its `validate()` function is Promise-returning, which I thought I could `await` in RF's synchronous `validate()` function but there is no way to actually wait for the promise to settle before returning from `validate()` so that doesn't work.

It would work using `asyncValidate()`, but would you advise against repurposing `asyncValidate` for integrating a Promise-based validation library like this?